# How to add required field for Alt Text only for images not for other Multimedia Types?

Tags: sdl-tridion, schema

I have Mutimedia Schema allowing different multimedia types and need Alt Text required only for Images (png, jpg, gif,...) but not other formats (pdf,word, excel...).

How to restrict Alt Tag required for images only.

I'm using SDL Tridion 9.1.0

Answer (score 4):

If you require different sets of metadata for different Multimedia Types, you apparently require different Multimedia Schemas.

So, instead of one Multimedia Schema associated with all Multimedia Types, you should define multiple Multimedia Schemas associated with the appropriate Multimedia Types.

Comment: +1. For your example, Ajay, that might be an "Image" Multimedia Schema with the mandatory alt text field meant for images separate from a "File" or "Download" Schema for PDF, Word, Excel, etc. This then lets you separately manage such items, set a default Multimedia Schema for items created in a folder, and treat them differently when used in Content Delivery.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply :) But in my project having thousands of files created with this scheema, at this time separate for Images is difficult, is there any possibility to restrict using core Services or Custom Event..etc.